# How to log an exception declared in method signature

Tags: java, exception, log4j2

```
public void addTitleRow() throws SQLException{
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ANY")
    log.info ? }
```

How can I log an `exception` declared to be thrown in the method signature? I'm using **log4j2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to catch the exception first in order to to log it. You can suppress it or simply re-throw it later if you wish to.

Here is the code snippet:

**Re-Throw Exception:**

```
try {
    /* Do Something Here */
} catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error("An Exception Has Occurred!", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

**Suppress Exception:**

```
try {
    /* Do Something Here */
} catch (Exception ex) {
    log.warn("An Exception Has Occurred!", ex);
}
```